# how to make the whole row clickable and change the color angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

how can i make the whole row clickable and also when how to change the row color when i click the checkbox?

**here is my html file**

```
<section class="others">
<div class="sub-header">Others</div>
<p class="text-center" *ngIf="otherTests.length === 0">No Tests Available</p>
<app-custom-accordion [closeOthers]="true">
<ngb-panel [disabled]="true" *ngFor="let testPanel of otherTests" id=". {{testPanel.Id}}" [title]="testPanel.Name">
  <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
    <div class="action-items">
      <span class="material-icons fav" [class.favorited]="testPanel.Favorite" (click)="onFavoriteClick(testPanel)"></span>
      <span class="icon-set" [ngClass]="{'same-day-2x': isSameDay(testPanel.Code), 'next-day-2x': isNextDay(testPanel.Code)}"></span>
      <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [name]="testPanel.Id + '-' + testPanel.Moniker" [ngModel]="panelIds.indexOf(testPanel.Id) > -1"
        (ngModelChange)="onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event, testPanel)" [id]="testPanel.Id + '-' + testPanel.Moniker">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-panel>
```

**here is my Ts file for checkbox change**

```
onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event: boolean, panel: TestOrderPanel) {
let testPanelIds = panel.Tests.map(test => test.Id);
// Wipe any duplicates
this.panelIds = this.panelIds.filter(
  panelId => panel.Id !== panelId && testPanelIds.indexOf(panelId) === -1
);
this.selectedPanels = this.selectedPanels.filter(
  selectedPanel =>
    panel.Id !== selectedPanel.Id &&
    testPanelIds.indexOf(selectedPanel.Id) === -1
);

if ($event) {
  this.panelIds.push(panel.Id);
  this.selectedPanels.push(panel);
   }
  this.updateSession();
}
```

**this is my app-custom-accordion component**

```
 <div class="card">
 <ng-template ngFor let-panel [ngForOf]="panels">
<div role="tab" id="{{panel.id}}-header" [class]="'card-header ' + 
 (panel.type ? 'card-' + panel.type: type ? 'card-' + type : '')"
  [class.active]="isOpen(panel.id)">
  <a href (click)="!!toggle(panel.id)" [attr.tabindex]=" . 
 (panel.disabled 
  ? '-1' : null)" [attr.aria-expanded]="isOpen(panel.id)"
    [attr.aria-controls]="(isOpen(panel.id) ? panel.id : null)" 
 [attr.aria-disabled]="panel.disabled">{{panel.title}}</a>
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="panel.titleTpl?.templateRef"></ng- 
  template>
  <!-- expansion arrows -->
  <div *ngIf="arrowExpand" (click)="toggle(panel.id)" [attr.aria- 
  expanded]="isOpen(panel.id)">
    <span class="material-icons expand"></span>
  </div>

 </div>
 <div id="{{panel.id}}" role="tabpanel" [attr.aria-labelledby]="panel.id + '-header'" class="card-block" *ngIf="isOpen(panel.id) && panel.contentTpl">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="panel.contentTpl?.templateRef"></ng-template>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
```

how to change the color of whole row when click on checkbox 
like when checkbox is selected the whole row should be dark or whatever and when unchecked should go to previous color i.e white
can anyone help? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make whole row clickable with (click):

Example:

```
<div (click)="someFunction()"></div>
```

Makes the `div` clickable

To change color based on value of a checkbox you can enable and disable a class that applies color to the element like shown below:

```
<div [className]="valueOfCheckBox? 'example-class' : 'other-class'"></div>
```

In the above code the `valueOfCheckBox` will be the value of your `check-box` and `example-class` can be the `class` with color when it is checked and `other-class` can be `class` with color to show when it is unchecked.

You can also do the same with `style` like shown below:

```
<div [style.color]="valueOfCheckBox ? 'blue' : 'green'"></div>
```

Comment: do you want me to add className code into that div or what? @Thanthu

Comment: Yes, If it is the <div> that you want to color, and you have classes in you CSS with color's you want to apply. You use this for not just <div> but any HTML component that can have class attibute

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more with my code example
cannot produced the desired result @Thanthu

Comment: which HTML element in your code do you want to change color ? and what is the model of the check box

Comment: app-custom-accordion @Thanthu

Comment: Isn't that another angular component ? And what is the value that you are looking at to change the color, like the value of the check-box. In this case you'll have to pass that value to app-custom-accordion component using angular's @Input() like you are doing for [closeOthers] and use that value inside app-custom-accordion's html to choose css class or style like shown in answer

Comment: sorry that is another component and the value is testPanel.Id